# Exporting data from an Interpolating Function

Tags: export, finite-element-method

Apologies if this question is repetitive, but I have browsed the questions already posed on exporting data from NDSolve and haven't been able to successfully apply the information I found to my own needs. Given the specified boundary conditions for phi, I have used NDSolve to solve a PDE for the profile within the domain. I then used the results of the NDSolve in another equation, and it is the results of this equation that I would like to export. Basically, I am looking to export the values that I plotted in the code below. I attempted to create a table of the them, but what has ended up in the table is the input i.e. 'Ienum[7.5*10^-6,1/10000]' not the evaluation of Ienum at those coordinates. Below is the code I've developed; the relevant part is at the end, before then is just setting up the problem. If anyone has suggestions on how to put the results of Ienum into a table or can point me to a more helpful answer than those I've already viewed, that would be great!

```
(*Constants used in subsequent equations*)
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
l = 10*10^-6;
sige = 3.37*10^-5;
phi1 = 0;
phi2 = -5;
x1 = 0;
x2 = l;
y1 = 0;
y2 = 0.0025;
y3 = 0.0075;
y4 = 0.01;
(*Boundary conditions*)
bcphi = {DirichletCondition[
    phi[x, y] == phi1, (x == x1 && y1 < y < y4)], 
   DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == phi2, (x == x2 && y2 < y < y3)]};
(*Create mesh*)
meshRefine[vertices_, area_] := area > 10^-12;
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[True, {{x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y4}}]],
    MeshRefinementFunction -> meshRefine];
(*Solve for phi everywhere*)
solphi = NDSolve[{Laplacian[phi[x, y], {x, y}] == 
     0 + NeumannValue[0, 
       y == y1 || 
        y == y4 || (x == x2 && y1 <= y <= y2) || (x == x2 && 
          y3 <= y <= y4)], bcphi}, phi, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
(*Use the results of NDSolve in second equation*)
Ienum[x, y] = -sige*(D[phi[x, y] /. solphi, x] + 
     D[phi[x, y] /. solphi, y]);
(*Plot results*)
Plot[Ienum[x, y] /. x -> 0.0000075, {y, y3 - 0.00005, y3 + 0.00005}]
(*Export data*)
Iedata = Table[
   Flatten[{y, Evaluate[{Ienum[x, y] /. x -> 0.0000075}]}], {y,
     y3 - 0.00005, y3 + 0.00005, 10^-6}];
Export["Ie_data.csv", Iedata];
```

Comment: Could you not just Export the whole InterpolatingFunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your code slightly, you had mostly just two mistakes.

```
Ienum[x_, y_] := Evaluate[-sige*(D[phi[x, y] /. solphi, x] + 
  D[phi[x, y] /. solphi, y])];

Iedata = Table[{y, Ienum[0.0000075, y] // First}, {y, y3 - 0.00005, y3 + 0.00005, 10^-6}];


ListPlot[Iedata]
```

[image: []

You should have used := instead of equal, and set your Evaluate inside of that function instead of later on and set x_ and y_ to pass your variables.

Your data function I also slightly changed, it should be clearly to read whats happening I think.

Hope this helps, welcome to the community, don't forget to vote up and also mark any answers that answer your questions with the checkmark to the side!

Have a look at this [page for common syntax and other errors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) users encounter while using mathematica.