# Exporting data from a simply generated interpolating function

Tags: export, interpolation, conversion

The question referenced in the link [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215779/exporting-data-from-an-interpolating-function) has a title that matches my question, but the discussion is very complex and does not seem to address my issue. I have solved a partial differential equation using NDSolve, getting an InterpolatingFunction, and I need to export a mesh of interpolated values so that I can process the data in a Python scipt.

Here is my code

```
nsol1 = NDSolve[{D[y[x, t], t] + 2 D[y[x, t], x] == 3, 
   y[x, 0] == x + 3, y[5, t] == t + 8}, y[x, t], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 4}]
Plot3D[nsol1[[1, 1, 2]], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

It plots OK but I don't know how to extract numbers from the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nsol1 = NDSolve[{D[y[x, t], t] + 2 D[y[x, t], x] == 3, y[x, 0] == x + 3, 
     y[5, t] == t + 8}, y[x, t], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 4}][[1]];
```

For a mesh of interpolated values

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, t, y[x, t] /. nsol1}, {x, 0, 5, 1/2}, {t, 0, 4, 1/2}], 1];
```

Plotting,

```
Show[
 Plot3D[y[x, t] /. nsol1, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 4}],
 Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point[data]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

We can use the properties of the `InterpolatingFunction` object produced by `NDSolve` to get the list of coordinates:

First we get the interpolating function object from `nsol1`:

```
intF = nsol1[[1, 1, 2, 0]]
```

[image]

Available list of properties for `intF` can be obtained using `intF["Methods"]`:

```
intF["Methods"]
```

[image]

We can access the xt-coordinates used in interpolation using

```
grid = intF["Grid"];
grid // Short[#, 20] &
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[intF["Grid"]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `intF["Coordinates"]` to the lists of x and t coordinates and construct tuples of them to get the list of xt coordinates:

```
Join @@ intF["Grid"] == Tuples@intF["Coordinates"]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Similarly, we can use the property `"ValuesOnGrid"` to get the z values:

```
zlst = intF["ValuesOnGrid"];

Short[zlst, 20]
```

[image]

We can combine the `grid` and `zlist` to get the list of 3D coordinates used by `intF`:

```
xtz = Join[grid, Map[List, zlst, {-1}], 3];

Short[xtz, 10]
```

[image]

We get the x and t ranges using the property `"Domain"`:

```
intF["Domain"]
```

> ```
> {{0., 5.}, {0., 4.}}
> ```

Plot the surface and the coordinates used in interpolation:

```
Show[Plot3D[intF[x, t], {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> None], 
 ListPointPlot3D[xtz]]
```

[image]

To get the list of 3D coordinates in a single step, use

```
coords3D = Join @@ Join[intF["Grid"], Map[List, intF["ValuesOnGrid"], {-1}], 3];
```

Comment: (+1) excellent as always. Did not even know that we can extract the data like that. Awesome stuff!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words and upvote @kcr.

Comment: @kcr See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for bringing this to my attention. Very useful and educational!